# IntelliJ highlight everything as warning

Tags: java, intellij-idea

After change env JAVA_HOME from Java11 to Java8, IntelliJ started to highlight almost every line of code in my project as warning.
In pom.xml I have java 1.8
In module settings I have also java 8

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7WfA.png

Comment: Those are not warnings. The parts of code are highlighted for no apparent reason. Does the code still compile? Have you tried restarting IDEA?

Comment: yes, code is compiling, and I have restarted IDEA. Nothing changes

Comment: I removed project from computer, and downloaded from repo again, and that works. But don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you encounter strange issues with the IDE there are a couple of things you can do to resolve the issue without removing and reimporting the project.

1. Using a Build System such as Gradle or Maven you can try to [refresh the configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html#maven_reimport) by opening the "Gradle" or "Maven" view on the right hand side of IntelliJ and clicking Reload
2. In the top menu, select `Build -> Rebuild Project`
3. If all prior attempts fail, navigate to `File -> Invalidate Caches` and click `Invalidate and Restart`. It will force IntelliJ to re-index everything.

Those methods usually work.